# Smarty Rendering with Sub-Templates & Plugins

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm having a tough time trying to make my notification box appear within my template, powered by Smarty.

I have my main.tpl template:

```
{include file='header.tpl'}
{include file='notification.tpl'}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{eval var=$content}
{include file='footer.tpl'}
```

In notification.tpl:

```
{if $notification}
<div id="notifications">
{foreach $notification as $detail}
    <div class="{$detail.type}">
        <p><span class="title">{$detail.title}</span><br>{$detail.content}</p>
    </div>
{/foreach}
</div>
{/if}
```

In my index.php page that powers smarty, includes classes, etc, it basics has:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();

// some details removed for simplicity

// $content is from the database
$smarty->assign("content", $content);
$smarty->assign("notification", $registry->notifications->render());
echo $smarty->fetch('main.tpl');
```

Within $content, above, the following is included:

```
<p>Have an account with us? Login to your account below:</p>
{widget name="login"}
```

I've made a plugin and a class to deal with my widget plugin - the above works perfectly (the form is included and can login). However, I'm trying to add some details to the notification area on the main template if a bad username/password was enetered, yet I cannot seem to do this within my widget plugin for some reason.

My function.widget.php file:

```
function smarty_function_widget($params, $template){
    if(empty($params['name'])){
        user_error('Widget is missing name.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if(file_exists($controller = sprintf('%s/controller.php', WIDGETS_PATH . strtolower($params['name'])))){
        require_once($controller);
    } else {
        // Hide the unfound widget from the end user
        eval(sprintf('class %s extends Smarty_Widget {}', strtolower($params['name'])));
    }

    $widget = call_user_func($params['name'] . '::factory', $params);
    $widget->loadView($template->smarty)->execute($widget);
}
```

My widget class, widget.class.php:

```
class Smarty_Widget {

    protected $smarty;
    protected $view = 'default';
    public $ext = '.tpl';
    public $_vars = array();
    public $widget_dir = WIDGETS_PATH;
    public $widget_template_dir;
    public $registry;

    final public static function factory($params = array()){
        $className = get_called_class();
        return new $className($params);
    }

    private function __construct($params){
        global $registry;

        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->_vars = $params;
        unset($params, $this->_vars['name']);
    }

    final public function loadView($smarty){
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
        $this->smarty->assign($this->_vars);
        $this->widget_template_dir = $this->smarty->getTemplateDir('0') . 'widgets/';

        return $this;
    }

    final protected function display(){
        $className = strtolower(get_called_class());

        if(is_file($this->widget_template_dir . $className . '/' . $this->view . $this->ext)){
            // Only display is exists
            $this->smarty->display($this->widget_template_dir . $className . '/' . $this->view . $this->ext);
        }
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->display();
    }
}
```

My notification class does work if I add a notification within index.php where it is rendered. However, for some reason these notifications do not appear if I add them within the widget's plugin (function.widget.php). Is there some pre-rendering place that I should assign the notification details, as it seems all sub-items are processed much later but since it is already declared then it won't add it in.

So my question is, where should I assign the notification part correctly, given that I could always have 2 widgets on a page, so don't want to display every error twice.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood you correctly but have tried to define your main.tpl as parent template and the home.tpl as child template like so.. main: `{$notification}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{block name='loginarea'}{widget name="login"}{/block}` home: `{extends file="main.tpl"}`

Comment: I think I could improve how I wrote the above - I may have stripped out too much in order to simplify it here (my bad). Give me about 5/10 minutes

Comment: You can try to pre-fetch the widget output like `$smarty->assign("content",$smarty->fetch('text:<p>Have an account with us? Login to your account below:</p>{widget name="login"}'));`

Comment: Smarty doesn't seem to like `$smarty->fetch('text: ...')` in this position - remove text also yields the following error... `Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unkown resource type '....`

Comment: my fault...try `string:` instead - i tested a sample case with it. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl

Comment: Hmm... seems to break once `{widget name="login"}` enters the mix, same happened with `eval` rather than string